# Xamrin Forms: Custom user registration with Azure Functions App

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, active-directory, registration, azure-functions

I am implementing a project using Xamrin Forms and have it pointing to an Azure Functions App.  I have configured the Azure Functions App to require authentication in the Azure Portal.

I am looking into creating a custom sign in / registration form with the following standard inputs:

1. user name
2. email address
3. password

I would like to restrict users from accessing my Azure Functions until they are authenticated via my custom sign in / registration procedure.  However I am not sure this is possible without using some standard authentication process like Active Directory (which uses a Microsoft Acccount) or Google / Facebook authentication.  Is there a way to authenticate users using a custom sign in / registration form in an Azure Functions app?  If so, how can I achieve this?

If this is possible I would be greatful if someone could point me out to code samples using Xamarin Forms to achive this.

Comment: What kind of login (email) do you want to use ? How people register to your app  ? Will you have a custom database to store users ?

Comment: I am trying to avoid requiring users to have to use a particular email provider (gmail / yahoo / microsoft) and I want them to be able to specify a user name, hence the custom registration form.  I am assuming I would need a custom database to store my users.  As for how they would register, they would have the 3 inputs I specified in the OP (user name, email address, password).

Comment: Have you tried Azure B2C or Auth0 they offer a service that handle most of the case

Comment: Following your reply I started looking into Azure B2C and it seems that the user sign in / sign up inputs as well as layout is configurable on the Azure Portal via policies / company branding.  Can you confirm this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding

Comment: You can also set pawword policy (min length, special characters...)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the brand configuration part.  I have also tried to find out _where_ to configure registration policies that determine what the user see's upon registration / sign in.  The only thing I could find was an outdated article:

[link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies[link]

I am unable to find out where to configure the policies mentioned in the article in the updated Azure interface.

Comment: think it will be in azure ad, I t depend sif you have premium version or not

Comment: Upon investigating this issue further it seems as you say, that one has to have premium AD for customer branding.  However as far as i'm concerned, _that_ particular feature can wait, what i'm more interested in is configuring sign in policies which would allow me to customize the sign in / login page.  Do you think I need premium AD for that as well?

Comment: I think it is a available for everyone, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy. You need to do it through powershell tho

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Thomas.  I think there has been a slight misunderstanding; the link you gave me is about setting restrictions around passwords only.  I am trying to configure what sign up fields the user will encounter (email, username, password) as well as the general layout of the sign in / registration form.   

I have been trying to find is an updated version of the following link which I mentioned earlier.  Whats described in it is exactly what I am trying to achieve:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies

Comment: Ohh sorry, so you have your answer ???? :-)

Comment: Having looked into it more I noted that there were prerequesites to creating sign in policies, namely creating B2C Tenants.  The policies are configred _within_ the tenants which is why I could not find them.  

Thanks to your input I am now on the right path - I know now that I should use Active Directory B2C which I was not aware of before I started this thread.  Before we conclude are you aware of some sample B2C sign in code that uses Xamarin Forms to give me a head start.

Also feel free to actually post an answer to this OP so I can confirm that you answered it, by suggesting B2C.

Comment: @Thomas Since you pointed me in the right direction for this issue (Azure AD B2C) feel free to post an answer to this question so that I can accept it.

Also, incase you are interested, I have posted another question as I am having trouble getting Active Directory to work with a sample.  My post can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059571/active-directory-msal-uwp-publicclientapplication-acquiretokensilentasync

Comment: I've posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

THere are some products that deals with Authentication As a Service:

- [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)
- [Azure AD B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b)

Both will allow you to use external providers such as google, facebook account and also to manage your own users database.

For Azure Ad, here are some interesting links:

- [Add company branding to your sign-in page in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding)
- [Password policies and restrictions in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy)
- [Azure Active Directory B2C: Built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies)