# Active Directory: MSAL (UWP) PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(...) returns exception

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to implement a sign in / login function using Active Directory.  I am basing myself in on this [b2c-xamarin sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native).

Below is the relevant code that I am having issues with.  I have made modifications here to simplify readability.  I have inserted comments for anything noteworty, particularly AcquireTokenAsync:

```
string ClientID     = "<application_id_of_b2c_application>"
string Authority    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>/<signin_policy_name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"

PublicClientApplication PCA = new PublicClientApplication(ClientID, Authority);

//  The application says to override this which I do not as I am not sure if its required for actual sign in
PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{ClientID}://auth";

//  UWP SIGN IN CODE
string Scopes = { "User.Read" };
string PolicySignUpSignIn = "<signin_policy_name>";

//  Arguments #2 and #3 both return null.  This happens also with the unmodified sample that works.
//  I do not know what to put in for argument #1 (scopes) - I have tried numerous combinations to no avail.  currently I have { "User.Read" }
AuthenticationResult ar = await PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(PCA.Users, PolicySignUpSignIn), PCA.UiParent);
```

The excpetion I get when calling AcquireTokenAsync is the following (truncated for readability purposes - I inserted the beginning and the end)

> {Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalException: WAB authentication failed
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified protocol is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800C000D)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    ...(TRUNCATION)...
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   UserDetailsClient.MainPage.d__2.MoveNext()
>     ErrorCode: authentication_ui_failed}

The way I see it the problem could be any of the following:

1. PublicClientApplication (PCA) was initialized with incorrect parameters (client id / authority)
2. I am using the wrong Scopes argument for AcquireTokenAsync - currently its: { "User.Read" }
3. I need to specify the proper redirect URI and assign it to PCA before calling AcquireTokenAsync in UWP
4. I am missing something on the Azure end

I have tried many combinations of arguments based on the values I have in Azure AD to no avail. I could really use some help.

Comment: For the point 1,it should be `string Authority    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<tenant>/<policy>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"`

Comment: Thanks for that specification.  I have made the change both in the code and in the OP, though the same exception is still being thrown.   At least that should be one less wrong parameter to worry about.

Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/28

Comment: In the title, it says you're using UWP...In the sample you are using, they are using the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.UWP/MainPage.xaml.cs#L26) to create the redirectUri for the app. The redirect Uri you have is for Xamarin iOS and Android. Here's more information on [client applications](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications). Which is why you are getting the error message that WAB auth failed.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been abroad for the last few days. I replaced the redirectUri with **urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob** as per the documentation you linked me to no avail.  Despite this I noted that WebAuthenticationBroker still returns the same exact long numerical string.  Could this be why I am still getting the same error?

The sample i'm basing myself on (again check the OP for link) is using UWP but also has android and IOS implementations. The UWP project of this sample with its default values runs and works on PC in that you are prompted to sign in via the app.

Comment: @andresm53  Having looked **matgutschow's** comment at your linked forum, I did not understand _which_ RedirectUri needed to be copied and more importantly _where_ it needed to be copied to (there is no reference to 'Custom Redirect URI') in the project.  Are you more familiar with this?

Comment: Hi, @Arkatakor. According to the error , it should be caused by the code:`authentication_ui_failed`. Also, the sample you posted is a bit mess, As Jenny's said , I cannot figure out which file are you using. Can you post more detials or look into the `UserDetailsClient.MainPage`.